# MultiClient in Python RAT

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing

I got inspired by Johan Godinho to create a [Remote Access Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH1DkiLc2mw) 
That is actually pretty cool and I think I am done with the basics and want to move forward by adding more features and make it more usefull. So I have worked on it by my own a little bit and published it on [github/LukasAlstrup/rat](https://github.com/LukasAlstrup/rat) 
I have a server and a client and I have come to the conclusion that it's pretty cool, but something is missing and that is multiple connections. There is a project called [Turtle](https://github.com/buckyroberts/Turtle/tree/master/Multiple_Clients), but it only supports CMD commands. Mine supports much more than that like screenshot, upload and download file. Turtle supports multiple clients at once using threads. Fantastic!
So I am asking for a way to implement multiclients into my project.

I have tried implementing it on my own, but I haven't really worked with classes and multiprocessing before, so it is pretty tough for me to make something like Turtle using classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While u use python it's better to apply the multi threading and you can handle clients by setup a class object for operations & an array to put the connected clients.

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean and thanks for the quick response (:

Comment: you will always got issues but would you search for solutions, try to make your own code version then we can guide after u gived it a try !

Comment: Hi chnz2k. I got it working. It supports multiple clients. I am so happy right now. I did it using the threading library in Python. Good day for you all (:

Comment: great to hear that ;)

Comment: @root Do you maybe still have the source code of your program? It sounds very interesting and I was wondering if you maybe had posted this somewhere on github?